# How to ensure one function does not run until after two functions?

Tags: angular

In one component, I have two functions `GetDataLabels()` and `GetData()` that have subscriptions that return moderately-large amounts of data into multiple object arrays each.  `GetData()` will sometimes need to be rerun due to user input, but `GetDataLabels()` will only need to be run once.  The results of `GetData()`'s subscription have to be interpreted with the results of `GetDataLabels()`, `ProcessData()`.

I am running into a problem where `GetData()`'s results cannot be processed because the results-processing part is trying to execute before `GetDataLabels()` has been completed.  How can I ensure that `ProcessData()` (or `GetData()` if I put `ProcessData()`'s functionality in with `GetData()`) won't run until `GetDataLabels()` has completed?

EDIT: The code looks roughly like this:

```
export class MyPageComponent implements OnInit {

  column1labels: any[] = [];
  column2labels: any[] = [];

  data: any[] = [];

  column1display = [];
  column2display = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    GetDataLabels();
    GetData();
    ProcessData();
  }

  GetDataLabels() {
    this.service.getDataLabels().subscribe{
      data=> {
        this.column1labels = data['column1'];
        this.column2labels = data['column2'];
      }
    }
  }

    GetData() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe{
      data=> {
        this.data = data;
      }
    }

   ProcessData() {
     this.data.foreach(e => {
       //this is where I get the errors
       //column1labels and column2labels are still empty when this code runs
       column1display.push(column1labels.find(f=> f.label_id == e.col1_id));
       column2display.push(column2labels.find(f=> f.label_id == e.col2_id));
     })
   }
  }

}
```

Comment: `ForkJoin`? `switchMap`? Show use the code? Create a stackblitz?

Comment: I don't know if a stackblitz is going to be helpful because the problem is a runtime problem dealing with Angular judging a specific database call - something I'd have to mock up - to be more time-consuming and therefore starting it early.

Comment: You are top-bottom wrong as you can use simply `delay` operator to simulate your scenario which will be far more deterministic than actual scenario.

Comment: if you struggle with rxjs, you can convert the http calls to promises by just calling toPromise() on them then you can just await all. Alternatevly for your problem i would look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/rxjs-operators-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned "GetData() will sometimes need to be rerun due to user input, but GetDataLabels() will only need to be run once."; have you thought about calling these functions sequentially instead of calling them all from `ngOnInit()`? I'd suggest refactoring the code like below:

** Please read the comments I have added in your code**

```
export class MyPageComponent implements OnInit {

  column1labels: any[] = [];
  column2labels: any[] = [];

  data: any[] = [];

  column1display = [];
  column2display = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    GetDataLabels();
  }

  GetDataLabels() {
    this.service.getDataLabels().subscribe{
      data=> {
        this.column1labels = data['column1'];
        this.column2labels = data['column2'];
        // call GetData() when you have received the data from GetDataLabels()
        this.GetData();
      }
    }
  }

    GetData() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe{
      data=> {
        this.data = data;
        // call ProcessData() when you have received the data from GetData()
        // At this point you will already have the data from GetDataLabels() available
        /**
         * Since GetDataLabels() only need to be called once,
         * any time user input changes, you can just re-run GetData(),
         * without executing GetDataLabels() multiple times.
        */
        this.ProcessData();
      }
    }

   ProcessData() {
     this.data.foreach(e => {
       //this is where I get the errors
       //column1labels and column2labels are still empty when this code runs
       column1display.push(column1labels.find(f=> f.label_id == e.col1_id));
       column2display.push(column2labels.find(f=> f.label_id == e.col2_id));
     })
   }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With what I understand you need to do a `combineLatest` between `GetDataLabels` & `GetData`.
But I miss information just paste the code/stream considerate.

Often in such case when you become stuck in the stream considered is because you need to go upstream and redefine it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `forkJoin` your requests as clearly you have to have `labels` and `data` before `ProcessData`

```
forkJoin({
   labels:this.service.getDataLabels(),
   data:this.service.getData()
}).subscribe(results=>{
    this.data=results.data;
    this.column1labels = results.labels.data['column1'];
    this.column2labels = results.labels.data['column2'];
    ProcessData(); //or even inline this as well.
})
```